# How can I get action command from show Confirm Dialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
if(s.equals("Skip"))
{
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Are You Sure...??");   
}
```

This is my code I want get command from show Confirm Dialog. If yes then skip if No then no skip and if cancel then dialog will cancel.

Answer (score 3):

[`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-)

> **Returns:**
>       an integer indicating the option selected by the user

Answer (score 3):

`showConfirmDialog` methods returns an integer, the possible values are:

- `YES_OPTION`
- `NO_OPTION`
- `CANCEL_OPTION`
- `OK_OPTION`
- `CLOSED_OPTION`

Based on above return value you can code.